# iOS – How to deal with notifications when I have no "control" of the GUI

Tags: objective-c, ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm using Apple's view controllers quite alot in my app (like `MFMessageComposeViewController` and `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`). So when I receive a notification (Local or Remote notification) how would I deal with it the most elegant way since I can not interact (send messages) to Apple's view controllers.

My assumption is that if the user is actively using the app and in i.e `MFMessageComposeViewController` he does not want to get disturbed/interrupted with what he is   doing. But if it was me I would get a bit confused if I was doing something and I would hear *boing* sound (from the notification) and then nothing more happened.

So would a reasonable way to handle this do let the user finish doing his task in whatever Apple view controller he is inside and then display the notification for the user?

**Or** dismiss the Apple view controller and handle the notifaction and then put the user back in the Apple view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understood you exactly correct, but to me it sound like you want to do something like this:

- If the user is composing a message in your app and there is an incoming notification, lets say a push notification from the facebook app, you want to handle this event somehow in your app by letting your MFMessageComposerViewController do something.

As answer to this request I would like to state the following:

1. You should be able to send messages to your MFMessageComposerViewController if you extend this class (i.e. create a class called MyMessageComposerController and let it extend the standard controller, and do whatever you need there)
2. However, you can't really do anything about the push notification, it comes from another app and this functionality is built into iOS, you can not make the push arrive later when the user is finished typing, it will always arrive and the user will always be the one to decide if he/she should keep typing or look at the notification. The only thing you can do is to make sure that your app saves everything that the user has typed so that he/she can continue typing when returning to your app.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) it says that the message composition interface must not be modified. And essentially what I want to do when my app receives a notification is to show an `UIAlertView`. Would Apple frown upon if I show an UIAlertView over `MFMMessageComposeViewController`? About the push notification I was referring to my own app's notifications.

Comment: I'm not sure how iOS treats the rest of your app when the message composer is open. If your app is still running behind the composer, then you might be able to show an alert from another class (by using performSelectorOnMainThread) or dismiss the message composer, or such things. You could probably also make sure you are not sending notifications while you are in the composer. However I'm not sure if your app is actually running behind the composer, or if it is treated as if in "background mode"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't just want to display an AlertView or something similarly modal over the message composer, I would do something like the following:

1. assign a `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` to the composer.
2. show the composer as usual.
3. queue/remember the notifications received while the composer is in play (through the normal `application:didReceive{Local|Remote}Notification:` messages)
4. when the composer is closed, the delegate receives its `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` message.
5. Do... whatever... with the stored/queued notifications.

Whether you delay responding to the notification until the user is finished with the composition or interrupt them is a trickier situation.  If it's a relatively unimportant notification or notifications that are frequent, I'd tend towards the queue/delay approach. But for "important" notifications, I'd have no problems in interrupting the user.  Of course, that just moves the question to what determines importance. And that is very much dependent on the app.